# How to use memcached (installed in different server) in php

Tags: php, mysql, windows, ubuntu, memcached

I have installed memcached in ubuntu 16 with PHP-7 and MySQL and my web application is in windows where I installed xampp with PHP-5.

I want to use memcached installed in ubuntu from my web application in windows.

Is it possible?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/memcache.connect.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your server to memcached server pool with `addServer` method.

```
<?php
    $m = new Memcached();
    $m->addServer('UBUNTU_SERVER_IP', 11211);
?>
```

for more information please check [Memcached::addServer](http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.addserver.php) on PHP Manual

Comment: This gives error in line 2 :
`Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Cache\Memcache' not found`

Comment: Shouldn't id be `Memcached`, with d at the end?

Comment: @Ajay maybe it is a namespace problem, please use  $m = new \Memcached();

Answer (score 0):

Example from PHP Manual:

```
<?php
$m = new Memcached();

/* Add 2 servers, so that the second one
   is twice as likely to be selected. */
$m->addServer('mem1.domain.com', 11211, 33);
$m->addServer('mem2.domain.com', 11211, 67);
?>
```

More informations:
[PHP:Memcached](http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.addserver.php)

After this don't forget to change in `/etc/memcached.conf` (Ubuntu)

```
# Specify which IP address to listen on. The default is to listen on all IP addresses
# This parameter is one of the only security measures that memcached has, so make sure
# it's listening on a firewalled interface.
-l 127.0.0.1
```

to

```
-l 0.0.0.0
```

and then

```
/etc/init.d/memcached restart
```

Comment: Memcached is working fine in ubuntu but I can not use the service of it  in another server.
So these changes is not needed.